# System.FormatException: 24201: Latitude values must be between -90 and 90 degrees. using wkb data vbbinary

Tags: sql-server-2008

```
INSERT INTO [Spatial].[dbo].spatial5
           (
           [WKB_GEOMETRY]
           )
           (
SELECT       geography::STPolyFromWKB(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


)
```

Comment: a whole page of characters, what do you want ?

Comment: I think I'm blind now..

Comment: The parameter contain wkb format data and it contains polygon , i just want to convert that wkb data in spatial type so we can see it for example DECLARE @g geography; 
SET @g = geography::STPolyFromWKB(0x01030000000100000005000000F4FDD478E9965EC0DD24068195D3474083C0CAA145965EC0508D976E12D3474083C0CAA145965EC04E62105839D44740F4FDD478E9965EC04E62105839D44740F4FDD478E9965EC0DD24068195D34740, 4326);
SELECT @g.ToString();
Gives result as POLYGON ((-122.358 47.653, -122.348 47.649, -122.348 47.658, -122.358 47.658, -122.358 47.653)), that is not i am getting from my query

Comment: Hi Soner thanks for your review , I just want to convert STPolyFromWKB(0x010...) data in spatial type means in geography or geometry